# What's difference between namespace v8 and namespace v8::internal?

Tags: c++, v8

While I was reading the v8's source code, I've got a part that I don't know very well.

```cpp
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
```

I tracked that the implementation of v8::Isolate::New, then I found following code:

```cpp
// static
Isolate* Isolate::Allocate() {
  return reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(i::Isolate::New());
}
```

Because I read the code a little more, I know that 'i' means 'internal', but I'm not sure about the rest. Are v8::Isolate and v8::internal::Isolate compatible?

Comment: internal means it isn't part of the public API. You shouldn't use internal stuff.

Comment: I don't know this particular library, but "internal" usually means "don't use it". It's subject to change. Library provides some interface to you which could only change with new major version, but internals don't have this guarantee and can change always. Also, there's likely no guarantee that using internals will not break your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, C++ libraries use an `internal` (also commonly called `detail`) namespace whenever they need to declare/define stuff that is used by the library, but shouldn't be used by the users.

It is a way to have something resembling "library linkage". Hopefully if/when modules arrive to C++, we will have a better way to handle this.